# Derivation on $C(X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

If we define derivation on $C(X)$, where $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, will the dimension of $Der(C(X))$(if it is well-defined) equal to the (topological) dimension of $X$? My guess is this is true since derivation is just differentiation of function, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: $C(X)$ consists of continuous functions so there are not obviously any nonzero derivations on $C(X)$ at all.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan its not entirely clear to me what your comment means (I can't parse it)

Comment: I mean you say "derivation is just differentiation of function" and that argument would apply to the smooth functions $C^{\infty}(M)$ on a smooth manifold, but looking at just the continuous functions on a compact Hausdorff space there is no obvious notion of differentiation available (even if that compact Hausdorff space happens to be a manifold).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $D$ is a derivation and $f\in C(X)$. For $x\in X$ look at $(Df)\,(x)$, since $D$ applied to any constant function is necessarily $0$ you have
$$(Df)\,(x) = D(f-c )\, (x)$$
with $c$ a constant function. Now for $c=f(x)$ you have that $f-c$ is $0$ at $x$. You may check that there exist $g,h$ continuous with $f-c= g\cdot h$ and $g(x)=h(x)=0$ (this is a feature of continuous functions that fundamentally fails for any notion of differentiable functions). Then

$$(Df)\, (x) = D(f-c)\,(x) =D(g\cdot h)\,(x)= g(x) (Dh)\,(x)+(Dg)\,(x)\,h(x) =0$$

hence $Df$ is zero at $x$ for any $x\in X$. This implies $D=0$ so there are no non-zero derivations.

Comment: May you further explain the property that $f-c=gh$, and why it fails on differentiable function?

Comment: Consider the function $x\mapsto x$ on $[-1,1]$, which is zero at $0$. Can you find two continuous functions $g,h$ with $x= g(x)h(x)$ and $g(0)=0=h(0)$? What about for differentiable $g,h$? Once you have understood how to get $g,h$ for this example you can find the expression for an aribtrary $f$ rather easily.